# Which bean converts Objects to Json in Spring Boot?

Tags: json, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot (MVC) application. I need a conversion from a Map to Json in code (not when returning a result from a web request). But I would like to use the same bean that Spring uses when doing that automatically. Which bean is doing that?

Comment: Spring uses Jackson ObjectMapper class. You can use the same

Comment: The controller should return you beans as JSON because it has ObjectMapper doing that for you. Check the headers for the return type

Comment: @ pvpkiran: Do they use it as bean directly? Can I get it by autoinjection?

Comment: @JPRLCol: as I understand it, controllers typically return values, not beans

Comment: Seems to be org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Comment: The Message Converter uses jackson.

Comment: @Gustave can u accept the answer

Answer (score 6):

Spring uses Jackson ObjectMapper class to do Json Serialization and Deserialization.

You can Autowire Objectmapper in the class you want to use. And then you can do

```
mapper.writeValueAsString(...)//You can pass any object to this method.
```

You can create a new Instance with `new ObjectMapper()`, if you want to do it in a standalone application. But since you are using spring-bootm ObjectMapper bean is already there which you can just Autowire